# What Free Methods of Elemental Specialization Exist in Anima

Tags: character-creation, optimization, anima-beyond-fantasy

I'm aware of the ability of Beings Between Worlds and Souls to specialize in an element of their choice given in Chapter 26 of the Core rulebook and the ability of Ki-users to specialize their techniques to reduce the cost.  I think I remember there was some way for a character to specialize their Magic Projection and maybe Resistance (MR/PhR) that didn't involve DP or CP but I can't seem to find it.  What choices that don't cost DP or CP can a player make during character creation to specialize/gain attunement in an element and where in the Core Rulebook are the rules regarding that choice?  Core Rulebook material only, please.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm assuming you're asking about magic specifically.

It's an advantage in the core rule book called Elemental Compatibility. It costs 1 advantage point. There is also a higher tiered version of it called Half-Attuned to the Tree (which costs 2). 
They both increase Magic Accumulation and MR for the chosen paths, and decrease it for the opposing paths.

Aside from that, I'm unaware of any others.

They can be found on pages 17 and 18 respectively.